# Making an alias for Temp Remove

Tags: bash, alias

I want to make an alias in bash to do this:
`mv -vi SomeFile_or_Directory /tmp` and use it instead of dangerous `rm`

I'm using a script(placed in `/usr/bin/`) to do this now, but I'd like to use an alias instead.

the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $@
do
   mv -vi $i /tmp
done
```

I tried `alias t='for i in $@;do;mv -vi $i /tmp;done'` but it didn't work.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function instead:

```
t () {
    for i in "$@"; do
        mv -vi -- "$i" /tmp
    done
}
```

Comment: actually tried this one too, just thought it won't be a good idea to put a function in `.bashrc`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with defining functions to put in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case an alias won't work; cuz aliases don't support control flow completely.

Put the function or the script in your `.profile`. That way you can access the command from other shells, e.g. zsh.